# Are you supposed to say "quelqu’un de mieux" or "quelqu’un de meilleur"?

Tags: grammaire, usage, choix-de-mot

Which locution is proper or better, as for example in "you deserve someone better than him, and everyone knows it except you!"?

Answer (score 5):

I would say "Tu mérites mieux et tu es le seul à ne pas t'en rendre compte".

In this context I would not specify "quelqu'un".

Or you can also say : "Tu mérites mieux que lui/elle"

Anyway, I will never say "quelqu'un de meilleur".

Answer (score 2):

Both can be used, but the meaning would be slightly different:

> *Tu mérites quelqu'un de **mieux** que lui*

***Mieux*** is here an invariable adjective which means "better in general, subjective, possibly in apparence (handsome vs ugly) or behavior (a gentleman vs rude)". This is likely the form to use in the question context.

> *Tu mérites quelqu'un de **meilleur** que lui.*

***Meilleur*** is a regular adjective which means "better in some specific quantifiable domain, intellectual or physical" (*meilleur en maths, meilleur en anglais, meilleur en saut à la perche...*)

Answer (score 2):

- [meilleur](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/meilleur) est le comparatif de supériorité de [bon](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bon)
- [mieux](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mieux) est le comparatif de supériorité de [bien](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bien)

« bon » et « bien » ont sensiblement la même traduction en anglais, à savoir : good, well, right