# "de meilleur" vs. "de mieux"

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, adverbes

Voilà quelques extraits des chansons :

"Tomber la chemise" de Zebda :

> Et tout ce que la colère a fait de meilleur

"On ira" de Zaz :

> Et l'on saura donner ce que l'on a de meilleur

Pourquoi ne chantent-ils pas "de mieux" ? N'est-ce pas un cas dans lequel on utiliserait l'adverbe ?

Comment: Dans les deux cas, il s'agit d'un adjectif. Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36719/1109

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C'est à cause des [rimes](https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/la-disposition-de-la-rime-f1430) des chansons à mon avis. Si elles utilisaient **mieux**, les rimes seraient incorrectes. On voit dans les deux cas que le mot **meilleur** est là pour rimer avec *ailleurs*.

Par contre, les adjectifs ne veulent pas exactement dire la même chose comme dit en commentaire, mais je ne sais pas à quel point cette différence a été importante pour l'auteur par rapport aux rimes de la chanson.

Zebda

> ...
>  Tous les enfants de ma cité et même d'ail**leur**s
>  Et tout
> ce que la colère a fait de meil**leur**
>  Des faces de stalagmites
> et des jolies filles
>  Des têtes d'acné, en un mot la famille
> ...

Zaz

> ...
>  On dira que les rencontres font les plus beaux voyages
>  On
> verra qu'on ne mérite que ce qui se partage
>  On entendra chanter
> des musiques d’ail**leur**s
>  Et l'on saura donner ce que l'on a de
> meil**leur**
>  ...

Answer (score 0):

Non, il n'est pas necessaire d'utiliser le mot "mieux" et le choix du mot "meilleur" dans les paroles de Zebda est tout à fait justifié, et non pas guidé par le besoin des rimes. En français, le mot "meilleur" précédé d'un article ("le", "son", "du", "de" etc...) est le superlatif relatif de "bon". Il est couramment employé de manière similaire aux exemples que vous avez partagés:

> C'est son meilleur ami.

> Servez-moi le meilleur vin.

> Tout est pour le mieux dans le meilleur des mondes possibles. (Candide, de Voltaire)

> Que le meilleur gagne !

> donner le meilleur de soi-même  (expression courante de la langue française: https://www.wordreference.com/fren/donner%20le%20meilleur%20de%20soi-m%C3%AAme)